# How can you block or edit a native browser form popup/alert?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, browser

I have a form that takes in a number as input and has max value set. I display a custom error when the user enters a value > the max value, but the native error pop-up is also visible. Is there any way I can block the native error pop-up or edit the text of the pop up?

Edit: I can't just remove the max attribute to get rid of the pop-up because it's used by several other functions with the site.

Edit 2: edited the question a little bit

[image: The native popup.]

Answer (score 0):

You should have your code inside an html form. Add the attribute `novalidate` to your form and it should disappear.

```
<form novalidate>
```

I hope it helps

Comment: I can't invalidate it because the validation might be used somewhere else on the site and since I just started working on this I don't want to make the assumption that it's not. I am looking to just block the popup or edit the text in the pop up if possible.

Comment: Try to run this JavaScript `$('form').attr('novalidate', '');`

Answer (score 0):

So you have both html validation and wrote custom validation logics to show the error message?

You might move the 'max' attribute in form field and have that in your validation logics. This also improves visual consistency of your error messages shown.

Comment: As I said in the edit, I can't move the max. Mainly because I don't where the other validation logistics are since I just started working on this. Is there a way to edit the text of the popup?